# Resizing iframes based on content changes for cross-origin content?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to resize iframes based on content changes for cross-origin content. Also I am trying open someone else's website in to my iframe so I don't have access to their site. Is there a way to do so?

```js
function resizeIFrameToFitContent(iFrame) {
  iFrame.width = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;
  iFrame.height = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  var iFrame = document.getElementById('iFrame1');
  resizeIFrameToFitContent(iFrame);
  // or, to resize all iframes:
  var iframes = document.querySelectorAll("iframe");
  for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    resizeIFrameToFitContent(iframes[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<iframe src="usagelogs/default.aspx" id="iFrame1"></iframe>
```

Comment: This is almost impossible, since it's cross origin. You essentially need something on the external site that allows JS to communicate.